# what is the difference in all flash player versions 8- 9 - 10 and now 10.2 or 3

Tags: apache-flex

what is the difference in all flash player versions 8- 9 - 10 and now 10.2 or 3. What is updated periodically. Why this versions shows difference in the memory issue.

Comment: Never heard of update logs? Why do you care anyway. If the difference in memory usage is an issue there is nothing you can do about it. You should always be using the latest version anyway.

Answer (score 6):

A google search would of been appropriate, but here's the content of the [Flash Player wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Player):

**Macromedia Flash Player 8**

- Support for runtime loading of GIF and PNG images
- New video codec (On2 VP6)
- Improved runtime performance and runtime bitmap caching
- Live filters and blendmodes
- File upload and download capabilities
- New text-rendering engine, the Saffron Type System
- ExternalAPI subsystem introduced to replace fscommand()

**Adobe Flash Player 9**

- New ECMAScript scripting engine, ActionScript Virtual Machine AVM2. AVM1 retained for compatibility.
- Actionscript 3 via AVM2.
- E4X, which is a new approach to parsing XML.
- Support for binary sockets.
- Support for Regular Expressions and namespaces.
- ECMAScript 4 virtual machine donated to Mozilla Foundation and named Tamarin.
- H.264
- AAC (HE-AAC, AAC Main Profile, and AAC-LC)
- New Flash Video file format F4V based on the ISO Base Media File Format (MPEG-4 Part 12)
- Support for container formats based on the ISO base media file format

**Adobe Flash Player 10**

- New Features
- 3D object transformations
- Custom filters via Pixel Bender
- Speex audio codec
- Real Time Media Flow Protocol (RTMFP)
- Dynamic sound generation
- Vector data type
- Enhanced Features
- Larger bitmap support
- Graphics drawing API
- Context menu
- Hardware acceleration
- Anti-aliasing engine (Saffron 3.1)
- Read/write clipboard access
- WMODE

**Adobe Flash Player 10.1**

- Reuse of Bitmap data copies for better memory management
- Improved garbage collector
- Hardware-based H.264 video decoding
- HTTP Dynamic Streaming
- Peer-assisted networking and Multicast
- Support for browser privacy modes
- Multi-touch APIs
- For Macs/OSX 10.4 ppc or later
- Using Cocoa UI for Macs
- Use of double-buffered OpenGL context for fullscreen
- Use of Core Animation

**Adobe Flash Player 10.2**

- Stage Video, a full hardware-accelerated video pipeline
- Internet Explorer 9 hardware-accelerated rendering support
- Custom native mouse cursors
- Multiple monitor full-screen support
- Enhanced sub-pixel rendering for text

Answer (score 1):

There can be two types of difference between versions of Flash Player:

1. From end user point of view.
2. From application developer point of view.

From the end user point of view differences are not so big. Performance, player size, security fixes.

But every new version of Flash Player brings new APIs, language and runtime environment changes. So with new versions of Flash Player end users can use web applications which uses these new advantages. For example, the latest public preview of Flash Player codenamed Molehill offer new level of 3D support. So developers can develop applications which leverages 3D APIs and end users can play realistic 3D games with that version of Player.

To see the particular differences follow [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Player#Release_history).